# How to Access Public Variables in a VB.Net Module Referenced in a C# Project?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, module, global-variables

I have a Visual Studio 2013 solution with a VB.Net project (GL2015 - compiling to a DLL) and a C# project (PBIS - compiling to a Windows Form). The GL2015 VB.Net DLL is referenced in my PBIS C# project. Basically I am incorporating a VB.NET app into my C# app. The VB.Net (GL2015) project has Modules, one of which contains nothing but global variables. I took it's input form and created one in my C# project. In porting over the code behind for the form in my C# app I noticed it is referencing these global variables.

Here's my question. How can I reference these 'global' variables from my C# project that are in the VB.Net module?

VB.Net GL2015 Project
Global_Stuff.vb

```
Public Module Global_Stuff

'These items should be populated by PBIS data:
Public CustomerName, CustomerLocation, EndUser, EndUserLocation, Application, PurchaseOrderNumber, JobProposalNumber, ItemNumber As String

Public MaterialsList As List(Of String)
Public ApplicationsPath, MaterialPropertiesFile, ETODBConnectionString As String
Public ErrorMessage As String
Public ExistingProposal, JobMode, ExistingJob As Boolean
End Module
```

C# PBIS Project GL2015Form.cs

```
using GL2015;
...
Global_Stuff.ApplicationsPath = nodeToFind.InnerText;
...
MaterialPropertiesFile = nodeToFind.InnerText;
```

I applied the using GL2015; directive at the top but couldn't reference the Global_Stuff module. This means that I would have to insert a 'Global_Stuff.' in front of all global variables referenced in the VB.NET project (see the ApplicationsPath.)

Is there any way to reference these global variables in the VB.NET project module without me having to qualify them in my C# project. There over 100 global variables that are referenced over 700 times in my C# project.

Comment: C# doesn't have a concept of a global variable, so there's not a lot you can do other than qualify it. I'm not sure if C#6's static `using` could apply here, I'd have to research if the vb is really creating a static class or not in the background.

Comment: In C#6, you would add a "using static Global_Stuff;" at the top and then you could access the (static) members of Global_Stuff directly. Prior to C#6, you are out of luck (not that it's that onerous to use a qualifier).

Comment: VB modules are compiled in exactly the same way as C# static classes.  The ability to use a module member unqualified in VB is syntactic sugar specific to that language in order to keep it in line with how VB6 worked with modules.  In C#, treat module members in the same way as you would static class members.  That means qualifying the member with the type name, which you can still do in VB too.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Modules in VB.Net to store Database Names WHY?
I got tired of typing the db name on other forms
OK so when I moved to C# WHAT no Modules
Here is my step by step solution for WinForms with C#

Create Two Forms Main entry form here is frmStart
My second form is frmDataModule
Here is the code in frmDataModule

```
    public partial class DataModule : Form
{
    public DataModule()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
    }
}
public class DBName
{
    // gv_dbName is used on frmStart
    public const string gv_dbName = "CheckBook.db";

}
```

OK here is the code on frmStart that uses the public const

```
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        string textToAdd = gv.strDatabase;
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(path))
            sw.Write(textToAdd + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
```

YES this is an old question I hope the LATE answer is helpful